# Python Class/Objects __str__ & other problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I'm *still* very new to Python, and am struggling with what should be a simple assignment. I have to write code for an 'Employee' class, save the module, import the module into another .py file and then store and display 3 objects of that class. I keep getting a

> `"TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)"`

no matter how I rework the code, and it's driving me nuts. Anything I've done wrong, please, explain to me how/why it's wrong, learning this is incredibly important to me!
The following is the code for the Employee class:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,id,dept,title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__id = id
        self.__dept = dept
        self.__title = title
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_id(self,id):
        self.__id = id
    def set_dept(self,dept):
        self.__dept = dept
    def set_title(self,title):
        self.__title = title
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id
    def get_dept(self):
        return self.__dept
    def get_title(self):
        return self.__title
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name: ',self.__name,'\n','ID Number: ',str(self.__id),'\n','Department: ',self.__dept,'\n','Job Title: ',self.__title
```

I'm not sure I need the set and/or get name methods, because the three objects I have to store and display are pre-determined (no user input or anything). The preceding code is saved in a file named emp.py. The following code is where I think the problem is, but being a novice I don't know for sure.

```
import emp
def main():
    name = 'Susan Meyers'
    id = '47899'
    dept = 'Accounting'
    title = 'Vice President'
    employee1 = emp.Employee(name,id,dept,title)
    name = 'Mark Jones'
    id = '39119'
    dept = 'IT'
    title = 'Programmer'
    employee2 = emp.Employee(name,id,dept,title)
    name = 'Joy Rogers'
    id = '81774'
    dept = 'Manufacturing'
    title = 'Engineer'
    employee3 = emp.Employee(name,id,dept,title)
    print('Employee 1:')
    print(employee1)
    print('Employee 2:')
    print(employee2)
    print('Employee 3: ')
    print(employee3)
main()
```

I've tried this by creating an object (i.e. susan = emp.Employee['Susan',id number,'dept','title'] with the appropriate information where id, dept, title are, but still get the tuple error. What am I doing wrong? I considered storing the information in a list or dictionary, but figured I should stick to the bare-bones basics. I feel so stupid, I've been at this all day! For any and all help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Fixed the indention errors (weren't present in my code in pycharm, but copying and pasting them here w/o proper proofreading...)
**FURTHER EDIT**:
When run, I need it to say:

```
Employee 1:
Name: Susan Meyers
ID Number: 47899
Department: Accounting
Title: Vice President

Employee 2:
Name: Mark Jones
ID Number: 39119
Department: IT
Title: Programmer

Employee 3:
Name: Joy Rogers
ID Number: 81774
Department: Manufacturing
Title: Engineer
```

**And that's the end of the program, like I said, should be *really* basic stuff, if this were a list or something, I could knock it out np... But each employee has to be stored as an object of the Employee class. We just covered an incredibly long chapter on Classes and Objects (while I was sick with the flu) so my recall/methods may not be the best.

Comment: can you also post your desired output? right now, your `__str__` is indeed returning tuple `("Name", "Susan Meyers", ...)` when `__str__` must return string. Changing the `__str__`'s return like this doesn't cause any problem as it returns **single** string: `return "Name: %s\nID Number: %s\nDepartment %s\nJob Title: %s" % (self.__name, self.__id, self.__dept, self.__title)`

Comment: You do not need getters and setters in Python, but write them anyway if your professor tells you to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error's with the `__str__` method itself

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Name: ',self.__name,'\n','ID Number: ',str(self.__id),'\n','Department: ',self.__dept,'\n','Job Title: ',self.__title
```

> `"TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)"`

This error notifies you that

```
'Name: ',self.__name,'\n','ID Number: ',str(self.__id),'\n','Department: ',self.__dept,'\n','Job Title: ',self.__title
```

is a **`tuple`**. (This is *implicitly* constructed from the comma-delimited notation.) However, Python is expecting a **`str`** as the return type. Change your return statement so that it returns a string. You can use

```
return ''.join(['Name: ',self.__name,'\n','ID Number: ',str(self.__id),'\n','Department: ',self.__dept,'\n','Job Title: ',self.__title])
```

or

```
return 'Name: {}\nID Number: {}\nDepartment: {}\nJob Title: {}'.format(self.__name, self.__id, self.__dept, self.__title)
```

or *anything* as long as it returns a string.

---

**Edit**: Clarification on Provided Solutions

The first solution uses the `.join()` method, which follows this format

```
<str_to_connect>.join(<iterable_of_str>)
```

The square brackets used `['Name: ',self.__name, ... self.__title]` will pack all your various string arguments into a **`list`**. Passing this list into `.join()` connects it all together into a single `str`.

The second solution uses the `.format()` method which follows this format

```
<str_to_format>.format(<args>...)
```

You can pass complex formatting into the `.format()` function, but they generally make use of a `{}` placeholder, which are then filled with input from the arguments passed.

The essential thing is that both these will **return `str` types**.

Further reading: [*`str.join()`*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join), [*PyFormat*](https://pyformat.info/).

*Note: C. Kim's solution in the comments, using `%`, is also equally valid.*

Comment: Note, op is probably used to using `print(a,b,c)` this way and may not understand the difference

Comment: That cleared it up (obviously), but could you please explain what the .join([]) method and the {} methods you used do? I understand that my str function was returning a tuple (but not quite *why* it was doing that, examples in the book coded the same way worked fine...), but I don't understand the two solutions you provided to make it *not* return a tuple. I'm still a struggling but determined student, and want to learn as much as possible, and then some. Thanks man!

Comment: @deHart I've clarified the examples I've provided and attached a couple links for further reference. Good luck with your learning!

Comment: @TrebuchetMS: From the bottom of my heart, thank you! That problem was driving my insane. Once you explained the commas were the problem, I realized I could simply concatenate (x+x+x) to fix the solution without using code I don't fully understand. Also, I'm neck-deep in another course assignment right now, but will check out those links as soon as I am able. Thank you for everything!

Comment: String concatenation _also_ works, since it will also return **`str`**. There's lot's of ways you could go about this, I only cherry-picked two of them. :-)